# Can emacs rgrep command be updated to exclude `node_modules` throughout a nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, emacs

I have recently begun using emacs as my default editor/IDE and have been generally happy with using rgrep to search projects for text. But if I use rgrep I don't get an option to exclude directories, specifically the node_modules directories. This results in longer searches and a lot of extraneous hits.

Can I change the base rgrep command to exclude those dirs when using rgrep in emacs when I'm in js2-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option would be to customize the `grep-find-ignored-directories` user option.

You possibly don't want to constrain this to `js2-mode`.  If you *were* to constrain it that way, you might go with something like:

```el
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'my-js2-mode-hook)

(defun my-js2-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `js2-mode'."
  (require 'grep)
  (setq-local grep-find-ignored-directories
              (cons "node_modules" (default-value 'grep-find-ignored-directories))))
```

However, there will surely be other buffers from which you might be initiating `rgrep` while still being within the same project.

Directory Local Variables provide an another approach (which can trivially account for all file-visiting buffers within a project, but will only apply to certain non-file-visiting buffers).

In practice, unless you feel that `node_modules` may be a directory name that you *wanted* to search under in some project types, I'd be inclined to just set the global value.

I'll also reference this feature of `grep-find-ignored-directories`:

> If an element is a cons cell, the car is called on the search directory
>   to determine whether cdr should not be recursed into.

In principle this provides the ability to filter directories on a case-by-case basis.  It's not the easiest thing to use, though -- it would necessitate that you *already* had code to identify whether or not a given directory was part of a project for which `node_modules` was safe/unsafe, and that code would once again need to work in any type of buffer, so you're still dealing with some of the same problems.  If you were using some other project-oriented libraries, though, then you might have some existing easy way of establishing the project *type*, which you could then use in a custom predicate function for that advanced filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this doesn't answer the question.  But it's possibly a better solution to the actual problem.

Presumably, you have this project under version control, and you've ignored `node_modules`.  If you use `ripgrep` (https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) it will automatically exclude anything ignored by the VCS.  Also it's way faster than `grep`.  I prefer `rg.el` (https://github.com/dajva/rg.el) in Emacs.